# What is the advantage of using forwarding references in range-based for loops?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, c++11, move-semantics

`const auto&` would suffice if I want to perform read-only operations. However, I have bumped into

```
for (auto&& e : v)  // v is non-const
```

a couple of times recently. This makes me wonder:

Is it possible that in some obscure corner cases there is some performance benefit in using forwarding references, compared to `auto&` or `const auto&`?

(`shared_ptr` is a suspect for obscure corner cases)

---

**Update**
Two examples that I found in my favorites:

[Any disadvantage of using const reference when iterating over basic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13057846/341970)
[Can I easily iterate over the values of a map using a range-based for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13087074/341970)

Please concentrate on the question: **why would I want to use auto&& in range-based for loops?**

Comment: Do you _really_ see it "often"?

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough context in your question for me to gauge how "crazy" it is where you're seeing it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Long story short: why would I want to use `auto&&` in range-based for loops?

Comment: See https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/15/autorefref-always-works/ and the (as of this writing, two) followup posts.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Thanks for the info. You might want to post a short summary as an answer, then link to your website. It would be better than just a comment.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The only advantage I can see is when the sequence iterator returns a proxy reference and you need to operate on that reference in a non-const way.  For example consider:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> v(10);
    for (auto& e : v)
        e = true;
}
```

This doesn't compile because rvalue `vector<bool>::reference` returned from the `iterator` won't bind to a non-const lvalue reference.  But this will work:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> v(10);
    for (auto&& e : v)
        e = true;
}
```

All that being said, I wouldn't code this way unless you knew you needed to satisfy such a use case.  I.e. I wouldn't do this gratuitously because it *does* cause people to wonder what you're up to.  And if I did do it, it wouldn't hurt to include a comment as to why:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> v(10);
    // using auto&& so that I can handle the rvalue reference
    //   returned for the vector<bool> case
    for (auto&& e : v)
        e = true;
}
```

**Edit**

This last case of mine should really be a template to make sense.  If you know the loop is always handling a proxy reference, then `auto` would work as well as `auto&&`.  But when the loop was sometimes handling non-proxy references and sometimes proxy-references, then I think `auto&&` would become the solution of choice.

Comment: On the other hand, there's no explicit _disadvantage_, is there? (Aside from potentially confusing people, which I don't think is much worth mentioning, personally.)

Comment: That's an interesting point. Presumably there's no way of encouraging range-`for` to prefer `T::const_iterator`? I believe `begin()` and `end()` are used. Seems like a bit of an oversight, except that you can use rvalue refs. So yeah maybe this is the answer.

Comment: Another term for writing code that unnecessarily confuses people is: writing confuscated code.  It is best to make your code as simple as possible, but no simpler.  This will help keep the bug count down.  That being said, as && becomes more familiar, then maybe 5 years from now people will come to expect an auto&& idiom (assuming it actually does no harm).  I don't know if that will happen or not.  But simple is in the eye of the beholder, and if you're writing for more than just yourself, take your readers into account.

Comment: I prefer `const auto&` when I want the compiler to help me check that I don't accidentally modify the elements in the sequence.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `template<class T> T const& as_const(T const& v){ return v; }` and `for(auto& e : as_const(v)) ...`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Ah, but `const T::iterator` is not `T::const_iterator`, right? i.e. does that actually work in this case? I suppose that's a different question. Looks like "yes" but I don't know why.

Comment: I personally like to use `auto&&` in generic code where I need to modify the elements of the sequence. If I don't, I'll just stick to `auto const&`.

Comment: @Xeo: +1 It is because of enthusiasts like yourself, constantly experimenting and pushing for better ways of doing things, that C++ continues to evolve.  Thank you. :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `std::begin` will delegate to calling member `begin`, which is overloaded on `const`.

Comment: Why isn't `auto&& e` an rvalue and therefore not possible to be assigned to? it's literally appearing on the left hand side here..

Comment: @Jonathan.: 7th paragraph of this section: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm#More%20on%20A&&  "Even though named rvalue references ..."

Comment: @HowardHinnant, thanks, i justed watched a presentation from Scott Meyers about this and it was immensely helpful with this and realising I'd misunderstood rvalue vs rvalue reference. I don't understand why universal references weren't actually a separate thing, part of the standard with a new token like `&&&`?

Comment: @Jonathan.:  It was a judgment call made at the time:  Kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: The top example compiles just fine in VS2015u2.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk:  With warnings on, it says it uses an extension to compile it.  It is a dangerous extension whose main use is backwards compatibility with pre-C++98 code.

Comment: @HowardHinnant hold on, what would that extension actually do? cheat `auto&` into `auto&&` behind our back?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk:  I don't really know.  Almost everything I know about VS, I glean from here: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net

Comment: "[...] then maybe 5 years from now people will come to expect an auto&& idiom [...]" 7 years later for(auto&& x : y) is still very confusing and definitely not an expected idiom.

Comment: In the case of using a single ampersand (lvalue reference) in `non-const` way a range-based for loop, why does `std::vector<bool>` gives a compilation error but `std::vector<int>` does not?

Comment: `vector<bool>` is not an array of `bool`, but is instead an array of bits made to look like an array of `bool`.  When one gets a "reference" to a bit, one actually gets a class type proxy reference (returned by value).  This rvalue proxy can not bind to a non-const lvalue reference.  More info here:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html

Comment: Would It be possible to use "auto const&&" when read-only suffices and "auto&&" for modifying the values? Would that be a more general version of "auto const&" and "auto&"?

Comment: `auto const&&` should work fine.  However I don't see any advantage (or any significant difference) between that and `auto const&`.

Comment: @Xeo however `auto const &` won't use `const_iterator`, but regular iterator under the hood. It shouldn't matter, but I prefer `for (auto && e : std::as_const(container))`.

Comment: The answer says : "This doesn't compile because rvalue ..."
But this does compile (and run) on Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: I believe VS has a non-conforming mode that allows rvalues to bind to non-const lvalue references.  I also believe they have a mode to catch that error at compile-time, but I'm not familiar enough with VS to say how to get that mode.  However this latter mode is conforming to the C++ standard, whereas the former is not.

Comment: Just a comment: This matters a lot more in C++20 where `v | std::views::transform(f)` becomes an easy way to make a range of rvalues.

Answer (score 33):

Using `auto&&` or [universal references](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) with a range-based `for`-loop has the advantage that you captures what you get. For most kinds of iterators you'll probably get either a `T&` or a `T const&` for some type `T`. The interesting case is where dereferencing an iterator yields a temporary: C++ 2011 got relaxed requirements and iterators aren't necessarily required to yield an lvalue. The use of universal references matches the argument forwarding in `std::for_each()`:

```
template <typename InIt, typename F>
F std::for_each(InIt it, InIt end, F f) {
    for (; it != end; ++it) {
        f(*it); // <---------------------- here
    }
    return f;
}
```

The function object `f` can treat `T&`, `T const&`, and `T` differently. Why should the body of a range-based `for`-loop be different? Of course, to actually take advantage of having deduced the type using universal references you'd need to pass them on correspondingly:

```
for (auto&& x: range) {
    f(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x));
}
```

Of course, using `std::forward()` means that you accept any returned values to be moved from. Whether objects like this makes much sense in non-template code I don't know (yet?). I can imagine that using universal references can offer more information to the compiler to do the Right Thing. In templated code it stays out of making any decision on what should happen with the objects.

Answer (score 11):

I virtually always use `auto&&`. Why get bitten by an edge case when you don't have to? It's shorter to type too, and I simply find it more... transparent. When you use `auto&& x`, then you know that `x` is exactly `*it`, every time.

Comment: My problem is that your are giving up `const`-ness with `auto&&` if `const auto&` suffices. The question asks for the corner cases where I can get bitten. What are the corner cases which have not been mentioned by Dietmar or Howard yet?

Comment: Here's a way to get bitten if you _do_ use `auto&&`.  If the type you are capturing should be moved in the body of the loop (for instance), and is changed to a later date so it resolves to a `const&` type, your code will silently continue functioning, but your moves will be come copies.  This code will be very deceptive.  If, however, you explicitly specify the type as an r-value reference, whoever changed the container type will get a compilation error because you really really wanted these objects moved and not copied...

Comment: @cyberbisson I just came across this: how can I enforce an rvalue reference without explicitly specify the type? Something like `for (std::decay_t<decltype(*v.begin())>&& e: v)`? I guess there is a better way ...

Comment: @JerryMa It depends on what you _do_ know about the type.  As mentioned above, `auto&&` will give a "universal reference", so anything other than that will get you a more specific type.  If `v` is assumed to be a `vector`, you could do `decltype(v)::value_type&&`, which is what I assume you wanted by taking the result of `operator*` on an iterator type.  You could also do `decltype(begin(v))::value_type&&` to check the iterator's types instead of the container.  If we have so little insight into the type, though, we might consider it a little clearer to just go with `auto&&`...

Comment: @Ali TBH classic constness (unlike constexpr) is one of the crapiest, least useful C++ features and an example of bad design. Because of lack of const constructors we ended up with `const_iterator/iterator`, `begin()/cbegin()`, lack of const propagation to the member in `unique_ptr` and other nonsense...  It's better to use `auto && `, which makes things simple.