# C++11 range-based for usage with auto

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, auto, rvalue-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the advantage of using universal references in range-based for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130708/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-universal-references-in-range-based-for-loops)

To iterate over the elements of a `vector<int>` to read them, I think the following usage of C++11 *range-based for* with `auto` is correct:

```
std::vector<int> v;
....
for (auto n : v)
{
   // Do something on n ...
   ....
}
```

If the elements stored in the container are not simple integers, but something "heavier", like say `std::string`s, my understanding is that to iterate over them in a `vector<string>` the correct usage of range-based for + `auto` is:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
....
for (const auto& s : v)
{
   // Do something on s ...
   ....
}
```

The use of `const &` avoids useless deep-copies, and should be OK since the loop code is just *observing* the content of the vector.

Is my understanding correct so far?

Now, I saw code that uses another form of `auto` in range-based for loops: `auto&&`, e.g.:

```
for (auto&& elem : container)
  ....
```

What is this usage good for? What is the advantage of using r-value references (`&&`) with range-based for loops? In what cases should we use this style?

Comment: search for reference collapse

Comment: Or "universal reference" - a term scott meyers coined for the template/auto && references

Comment: @Arne Mertz: Do you have a link to Meyers' coining of the term?  Just wanted to read what he had to say on the matter.

Comment: Sure, [here you go](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=universal+reference+meyers): first hit is the talk, fourth hit is the article on isocpp.org (at last we have C++ _Home_ page, yay!)