# Can't understand move semantics

Tags: c++

In a simple example like the following:

```
struct MyClass {
    MyClass() {}
    MyClass(const MyClass&) {}
};

int main(){
    std::vector<MyClass> objects;
    MyClass obj1;
    objects.push_back(obj1);
    for (auto&& obj: object) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

how does the auto&& work? The class doesn't have any move support, what is this code supposed to do? I don't understand..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the advantage of using universal references in range-based for loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130708/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-universal-references-in-range-based-for-loops)

Comment: You're nor using move semantics in your code.

Comment: @juanchopanza fine, but why does it compile? What is auto&& in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is deduced from the type obtained by dereferencing the sequence's iterator type; that is an *lvalue* reference, `MyClass&`. By the "reference collapsing" rules, trying to deduce the type "*rvalue* reference to *lvalue* reference" gives the *lvalue* reference type.

So `auto&&` is deduced to be `MyClass&`.

If the sequence had an iterator type that gave *rvalue* references, then it would instead be deduced as `MyClass&&`, enabling move semantics if the class supports them.