# c++ vector of vector with differents types

Tags: c++, vector

How can I declare and push_back a 2D vector of vector with differents types of variables. Is a vector the good way (is it better to use an array)?

my variables are like that :

```
int id;
string name;
int start;
int end;
```

and I would like to obtain a list :
((id1 name1 start1 end1), (id2 name2 start2 end2) ...

Sorry for this basic question but I used to work with python, which allow that.
Thanks

Comment: At its simplest, you probably want a vector of a `struct`.

Comment: Are you using c++ 11?

Comment: In order to use different type variables. Use void* pointers I think

Comment: @TalhaIrfan Are you serious ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want a 2D array, you want an array of records. Something like this:

```
struct Record
{
  int id;
  std::string name;
  int start;
  int end;
};

std::vector<Record> records;
```

Comment: @user3608663 this answer would save all your ids.  You're probably at a stage where researching what a `struct` is would be a good idea.

Comment: But if I put : records.id = 1 and after records.id=2 that's will replace 1 by 2, no?

Comment: @user3608663 If you want to learn C++, do it properly, from a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You don't do `records.id`, you do `records[42].id = 1;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `std::tuple` (C++11) to push tuples into the vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using record = std::tuple<int, std::string, int, int>;
    std::vector<record> v;
    v.emplace_back(1, "test1", 2, 3);
    v.emplace_back(10, "test2", 20, 30);

    for(auto&& elem: v) // display the elements
    {
        std::cout << std::get<0>(elem) << " ";
        std::cout << std::get<1>(elem) << " ";
        std::cout << std::get<2>(elem) << " ";
        std::cout << std::get<3>(elem) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `emplace_back` and get rid of the temporary.

Comment: No python, but I think it's the closest

Comment: Please replace auto&& by const auto&

Comment: @DieterLücking what's wrong with `auto&&`? I know that its only serious use case is http://stackoverflow.com/a/13130795/3093378 but why don't you like it here? Because of non-enforcing const-ness?

Comment: @vsoftco Please ignore my comment, I guess I learned something