# Maps - For Each (Ranged For) or Iterators?

Tags: c++

Imagine I had this map:

```
std::map<int, int> map;

map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(1, 1));
map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(2, 2));
map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(3, 3));
map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(4, 4));
map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(5, 5));
```

What would be the best to use?

This:

```
for(std::pair<int, int> pair : map) {} //or
for each(std::pair<int, int> pair in map) {}
```

Or this:

```
for(std::map<int, int>::iterator itr = map.begin(); itr != map.end(); itr++) {} //or
for(auto itr = map.begin(); itr != map.end(); itr++) {}
```

Comment: use range for. it is almost always a good choice

Comment: what is `for each` ? it's a non standard VS2011 extension

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki It's C++/CLI syntax, IIRC. (C++/CLI is an ECMA standard so while it's not standard C++, it's still a standard nonetheless.)

Comment: P.S. `for each(X in Y)` is nonstandard Microsoft C++; you should use `for(X : Y)` in C++.

Comment: Also note that the variable name `map` risks a conflict with `std::map`.

Comment: @Alex No, that's why namespaces. :-P

Comment: btw. that map's value type is `std::pair<const int, int>`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yep, that's why `auto` is so useful, less risk of getting it wrong. (But the OP was copy-constructing `std::pair<int, int>` from it so that was still valid.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young correct, but it's common practice to do `using std::map`.

Comment: @Alex I would call it *bad* practice, not *common* practice

Comment: By for each, I meant the range for. I've always seen it described as for each, which explains the title @PiotrSkotnicki .

Comment: @Alex I agree with Piotr, I've always seen/used std::map without using namespace std

Comment: I know this is done from personal experience, in my company we have our own map standard map type that lives in the global namespace, so I've grown keenly aware of this practice.

Comment: Also @nneonneo I guessed that, just put it there to properly explain what I meant :)

Comment: @Alex Putting anything in the global namespace is an antipattern. ;-)

Comment: Making absolute statements is an antipattern :P

Comment: `for (auto&& p : map)` to get what you almost always want by default

Comment: I invite you to read the excellent question, answers and comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130708/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-universal-references-in-range-based-for-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance perspective they are equivalent. The first two are generally preferred because they are much more readable.

Comment: Ah thanks. this is essentially what I wanted to know; I wondered if they had different performance, as I see iterators mentioned everywhere and the method I described above mentioned nowhere. Will accept answer when possible :)

Comment: @jay But you should still use `auto` (see my answer)!

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yeah, that's a valid point. I'm accepting this one due to the extra info, but thanks for the info you gave me :)

Comment: [for each in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx) is a non standard Microsoft extension that IMHO is not preferable as it is not portable.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah I know, I added that there just simply to explain a little bit better. I prefer `for(X : Y)` anyways :)

Comment: @NathanOliver C++/CLI is actually an ECMA standard so it's not correct to call it nonstandard, but of course it's not standard C++. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The best to use is:

```
for (auto&& entry : map)
```

Comment: The first creates unnecessary copies. The second can sometimes fail (not for maps, but in general). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130708/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-universal-references-in-range-based-for-loops