# Range-based for loop with decltype(auto)

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++14, auto, decltype

Is there a situation when `decltype(auto)` would be a better choice than `auto` (possibly with `&`, `&&`, or cv qualifiers) when using range-based for loops? In other words, would you ever write the following code?

```
for (decltype(auto) item : range) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`decltype(auto)` generates a different type when the input iterator returns by value.  `auto&&` creates an rvalue reference to the temporary, while `decltype(auto)` creates a local copy (in C++17 it just names the temporary because of the guaranteed elision change).

This has little difference.  In C++11/14, it requires a move ctor (that is not called in practice, but required) in the `decltype(auto)` case, but not in C++17.  In the `auto&&` the move ctor is not called and not required.

Another difference is the type of `decltype(item)`, which is a reference always with `auto&&`, but in the case of the temporary returning input iteraror `decltype(item)` is a value type.

That is about it.  In practice, I see no reason to `decltype(auto)` over `auto&&`.

As an aside, `auto&` forces non-rvalue, `const auto&` forces non-mutable, and `auto` forces a copy.  There are reasons to use `auto&&` instead of those, but that is outside the scope of this question.  `decltype(auto)` is closest to `auto&&`, so I compared those two.

Comment: `auto&&` is an rvalue reference here? I thought it was a universal/forwarding reference. Not claiming you're wrong--just trying to learn. :)

Comment: @erip : It is indeed a forwarding reference – "when the input iterator returns by value" then it creates an rvalue reference. ;-]

Comment: Totally overlooked that. Oops!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#decltype-auto):

> decltype(auto) is primarily useful for deducing the return type of forwarding functions and similar wrappers
>
> [...]
>
> although it can be used to declare local variables, doing that is probably just an antipattern since a local variable’s reference-ness should not depend on the initialization expression

That said, using a *forwarding reference* in a range-based for loop is the way to go.
As mentioned [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

> It is safe, and in fact, preferable in generic code, to use deduction to forwarding reference

I'd suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130708/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-universal-references-in-range-based-for-loops) question on SO for further details about using an universal reference in a range-based for loop.

Comment: "*Apart for the fact that they are currently named universal reference, the note is still valid.*" You have that backwards – Meyers gave them the ad hoc name 'universal references', but starting with C++17 the standard itself formally names them 'forwarding references'.

Comment: @ildjarn And you **are absolutely right**. I'm going to fix the answer. I ever mistake the two forms. Sorry and thank you.