# Why enumerate over a collection of items with a forwarding reference?

Tags: c++

Every now and then, I see something like this in my product's code base:

```
void ProcessDirectories(const std::vector<std::string>& paths)
{
    for (auto&& path : paths)
    {
        // Do something with path
    }
}
```

I would have expected this line instead:

```
    for (auto& path : paths)
```

Where `path` is a normal reference to the item in the collection being enumerated.

But what does this the "double ampersand thing" imply in the enumeration

```
    for (auto&& path : paths)
```

I understand this to be called [access by forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)  But what does it provide for a collection of strings?  I understand the basics of R-values and move semantics, but I don't admit expertise here.

Or perhaps a more general question if a collection of strings is uninteresting for the different type of reference enumerations: When is it appropriate to enumerate over a collection by forwarding reference?

Comment: I would usually use `const auto&`.

Comment: Fwiw, [Howard talked about this *here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130708/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-universal-references-in-range-based-for-loops). I concur with Jesper, though I maintain my `const` on the other side of type just as a matter of form (`auto const &`), Potato...uh. Potato.