# What is the difference between the two codes: for(auto x : v) and for(auto& x : v)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops

I am not able to understand the difference between these two codes as they are giving me same output?

```
void print() {
  int v[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
  for(auto x : v)
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

and

```
void increment() {
  int v[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
  for(auto& x : v) {
    cout << x << endl;
    ++x;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what `++x` does? Do you understand reference variables?

Comment: In one, `x` is (sequentially) a copy of each value in the array.  In the other, it is a reference to each value in the array.

Comment: yes i know what ++x does but i dont understand what you meant by reference variables? @BillLynch

Comment: In the first example, `x` is an `int` and, in the body of the loop, gives the value of the element being acted on.   Anything done to `x` will not affect an element of `v`, since it is a copy of the element.   In the second, `x` is a non-`const` reference (since you haven't specified `const`) to an element of `v`, so `++x` will increment that element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it better in C++ to pass by value or pass by constant reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference)

Answer (score 1):

The first code snippet will display each element of `v` array **without any reference** (i.e. their modified values won't be applied in the original `v` because that'll be just a copy.

On the other hand, the another snippet represents that it'll output the element first and then the element's value will get incremented whatever it is by one and the `v` will be altered.

Comment: What do you mean by "dominating"? I've not seen that terminology in this context before.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet `x` is a copy of an array element, in the second it's a reference. The second snippet does increment each element in the array, but you are not observing that.

The most *natural* way of writing the loop is

```
for (auto&& x : v) {
```

See [What is the advantage of using forwarding references in range-based for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130708/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-forwarding-references-in-range-based-for-loops/13130795#13130795) for an explanation.

In many ways it's a pity that the shorthand

```
for (x : v) {
```

(which would mean `auto&& x : v`) was not introduced into the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Both the code will give you the same output. But at the end of the `for` loop, the values of array `v` is different.

In the first, `x` is just another copy of the items in the array `v`. If you print again the value of the array `v` then it will be the same.

In the second, `x` is a reference of the given items in the array `v`. This code is printing the value and then increasing it by 1. If you print again the value of array `v` then all the elements in it are increased by 1.

Try the following code:

```
int v[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
cout << "Before :";
for(auto& x : v) {
    cout << x << ", ";
    ++x;
}
cout << endl << "After: ";
for (auto x: v) {
    cout << x << ", ";
}
```

You will get the following output:

```
Before: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,                                                                                                                                     
After: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
```

Basically, both of your code is having different values for the array `v` at the end of the `for` loop.