# Using lvalue reference v/s rvalue reference in a non-const way in a range-based for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, rvalue, lvalue

I've been trying to understand the difference between using *lvalue reference* v/s using *rvalue reference* in a `non-const` way a range-based for loop and stumbled upon this: [What is the advantage of using forwarding references in range-based for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130708/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-forwarding-references-in-range-based-for-loops)

However, I'm still not 100% clear on when to use which one. Because this

```
int main() {
    std::vector<bool> vec(5);
    for (auto &elem : vec)
        elem = true;
}
```

does not compile and gives this error:

```
main.cpp:7:23: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::_Bit_reference&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::_Bit_iterator::reference {aka std::_Bit_reference}’
     for (auto &elem : vec)
                       ^~~
```

So, here I should use *rvalue reference* (as I guess I don't have any other option, right!?)

But on the other hand, this

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec(5);
    for (auto &elem : vec)
        elem = 3;
}
```

gets compiled without any error! Why? I mean why does `std::vector<int>` get compiled but `std::vector<bool>` does not?

To me, it looks like *rvalue reference* works every time but let say for some reasons if I want to use *lvalue reference* then in which particular situations it will work and in which it won't? Also, why does *rvalue reference* works every time?

**Note:** In this question, my focus is only on updating/modifying elements in a range-based `for` loop, i.e. `non-const` way. I'm not talking about just accessing/reading them i.e. `const` way.

Comment: C++ made a boo-boo for specializing `std::vector<bool>` by packing it to save space.  Unfortunately, that means it behaves a little different than other `std::vector`.  I think it was a mistake, and they should have made `std::vector_bool` to be the packed one, and `std::vector<bool>` to be just like any other... but that ship has sailed.

Comment: @Eljay thank you so much for clarifying. I was so confused! 110% agree on having `std::vector_bool` as well as `std::vector<bool>`