# What is a proxy reference?

Tags: c++, proxy, reference

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13130795/10301017) to a question about when one would want to use a forwarding reference `auto&&` in a range-based for loop, where the author writes:

> The only advantage I can see is when the sequence iterator returns a **proxy reference** and you need to operate on that reference in a non-const way.

I could not find any easily accessible information about what a proxy reference is. What is it and why would one want to use it?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference