# How to loop a vector over a predefined range in C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to loop over a vector based on a predefined range?

I need something like this:

```
for(auto& it : myvector[0, 30])
```

Or:

```
for(auto& it : myvector[0-30])
```

Is this posible anyway?
I've tried both ways but it don't works.

Comment: [Take a look at `std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)

Comment: I'd seen this but cant understand the sample code... I there any easier way?

Comment: You could may your own vector range object (say `class vrange`), and use it like `for (auto& it : vrange(myvector, 0, 30))`

Comment: Also, `it` isn't an iterator as you maybe think. In range-based for loops like this the variable is directly a reference to the current iteration's element (which, unlike iterator, doesn't have to be dereferenced with `operator*`).

Comment: ¿Why don't you just use normal iteration with vector item index variable?

Comment: Probably because range-based `for` is next-to-impossible to <expletive deleted> up.

Comment: [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) has entered the chat. But I still like `std::span` more.

Answer (score 5):

the shortest code to do that is using an [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) as follow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <span>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4};
    // starting at 1, take 2 elements
    for (auto&& val: std::span(vec).subspan(1,2))
    {
        std::cout << val << '\n';  // print 2 and 3
    }
}
```

you can simplify the code with a helper as follows;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <span>
#include <cstdint>

// end exclusive
auto slice(auto& vec, size_t start, size_t end)
{
    return std::span(vec).subspan(start,end-start);
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4};
    for (auto&& val: slice(vec,1,3))
    {
        std::cout << val << '\n';
    }
}
```

this helper also works with C arrays. ex: `int vec[] = {1,2,3,4};` and std::array, `std::array<int, 4> vec = {1,2,3,4};`.

Edit: after writing this i realized this is the easiest way to segfault your application, so you should [assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) on the bounds when creating the span or clip to the bounds to protect the user passing an invalid range.

```
constexpr auto slice(auto& vec, size_t start, size_t end)
{
    assert(end <= std::size(vec));
    return std::span(vec).subspan(start,end-start);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you declare the loop variable as `auto&&` instead of just `auto&` or `auto const&`?

Comment: @ComicSansMS i can't remember the exact reason right now, but i recall something along the lines of "if the iterated object returns a temporary, then the `auto&&` will do lifetime extension and you can move out of it", i'll get back to you with exact info.

Comment: @ComicSansMS i found it [What is the advantage of using forwarding references in range-based for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13130795/15649230), `auto&` won't compile for `vector<bool>`, i just made it a habit for myself to always iterate with `auto&&` to avoid copies, but `auto const&` is better for const correctness.

Comment: Use `int` and be done with it  — in many cases (not all) `auto` is not needed.

Comment: `const auto &` will also take a temporary, and if you don't need to modify the value in the loop and can use `const`, the compiler may be able to take advantage and optimize things further.

Comment: @anatolyg each container has its own rules and gotchas, the only 2 statements that always do the right thing are `auto&&` and `auto const&`, and you spare yourself a few minutes of thinking about the edge cases when writing the loop, the choice of whether this loop modifies the container is the only thing you have to think about, which we have already spent 6 comments arguing about

Answer (score 0):

Proper use of `<ranges>` can solve this problem. The syntax is a bit more verbose, but readable and simple:

```
#include <ranges>
namespace sv=std::views;
//Now create a view on range [10, 30):
auto my_view = myvector | sv::drop(10) | sv::take(30-10);
//Now create a view on range [5, 15):
auto my_view2 = myvector | sv::take(15) | sv::drop(5)
for(auto& x : my_view)/*...*/;
for(auto& x : my_view2)/*...*/;
```

If the initial index is supposed to be 0, just omit the `drop` view and keep the `take`.
You can also use `counted` instead of `take`. But `counted` may overrun the buffer, while `take` is guaranteed to not exceed the `end` of the original range.