# Is a reference more efficient than a copy for small types in a range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've recently started to use range-based for (after gaining the compiler functionality). I've noticed that the preferred form to use a range-based for is this:

```
for(const auto& it: container) {...}
```

which makes sense for any type larger than an int. However, what if the container holds raw pointers (which was my case), or a smaller type?

Specifically, what I would like to know is:

1) Is it possible to incur a performance penalty by requesting a reference instead of a (possibly) smaller copy? What if the size of the type is exactly equal to the size of a native pointer?

2) Conversely, is it possible to incur a performance penalty by NOT using a reference? (because I find it likely that the compiler can perform a few optimizations in the case of a range-based for)

Note that I am asking for some insight into possible compiler behavior, not the C++ standard.

Comment: Well if you need a reference, you need a reference. Your question will make sense if you constrain the container to be const, or change the value type to `const auto& it`.

Comment: @GManNickG Sigh, yes, I did not mean that I would use the reference to alter the container. Obviously that wasn't clear enough.

Comment: On some machines pointers are 4 bytes and some are 8 bytes. If you're on a machine where they're 8 bytes, then copying `int`s should be faster than copying references. But it won't be a big difference.

Comment: Writing `for(auto&& it: container)` can have interesting implications as well, see [What is the advantage of using universal references in range-based for loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13130708/341970)

Comment: @Ali Thanks. I also found [Any disadvantage of using const reference when iterating over basic types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057596/any-disadvantage-of-using-const-reference-when-iterating-over-basic-types/13057846#13057846) I think between those I got what I wanted.

Comment: @AndreiTita Well, good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you do inside the loop.

If you look at "it" only once, there should be no difference, because the compiler has to *anyway* look for the address first and then dereference it to get the value.

If you look at "it" multiple times, it *might* make a difference due to memory consistency stuff -- if you write to something that *might* alias with "it", it would have to reload the value again and again.

But as always, use a profiler to solve only those performance problems that are really there.

Comment: +1 for "use a profiler to solve only those performance problems that are really there."